# Is it possible to get the value of startDate datetimepicker jquery?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

Is there a way to get the value of startDate in bootstrap datetimepicker?.
To be specific the year of the startDate
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
       endDate : '+4y +1m',
       startDate: '-1y -10m'
});
```

My startDart would be 2015 because 2016 - 1year.
After setting my startDate to be 2015. Now i want to get the value of my startDate in year format. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you be more clear on question...what exactly you are expecting here

Comment: @Geeky i updated my question

Comment: you mean you want to get startdates year?

Comment: @Geeky yes is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            endDate: '+4y +1m',
            startDate: '-1y -10m'
        });
        var startYear = $('#datepicker').data('datepicker').o.startDate.getFullYear();
        console.log(startYear);
```